# Syntax error from gulp-ruby-sass seems incorrect

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am creating a gulp task using ['gulp-ruby-sass'](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass) and I getting this error back in the terminal.

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
Load paths:
            /Users/antonioortiz/Sites/_test/_aortizRefresh_
            /Users/antonioortiz/Sites/_test/_aortizRefresh_/source/assets/sass
    on line 38 of /Users/antonioortiz/Sites/_test/_aortizRefresh_/source/assets/sass/style.scss
```

My compass version is `Compass 0.12.4 (Alnilam)`

And my version of sass is `Sass 3.2.18 (Media Mark)`

This is some excerpts of my gulfile.js

```
 var sassSources = ['source/assets/sass/style.scss'];

 gulp.task('sass', function(){
 gulp.src(sassSources)
        .pipe(sass({style:'expanded', lineNumbers:true}))
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('source/stylesheets'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {

   var server = livereload();
   gulp.watch(jsSources,['js']); 
   gulp.watch(sassSources,['sass']); 
   gulp.watch(['javascript/script.js', 'source/*.html'], function(e){
   server.changed(e.path);
  });
});

gulp.task('default', [ 'sass', 'js', 'watch']);
```

Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

The error message talks by itself : the `sass` could not find your `compass import`.

Using the `gulp-ruby-sass`, there is a `compass` boolean that you must set to `true` in order to get `compass` working with your `sass`.

Here is the corrected task :

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src(sassSources)
    .pipe(sass({ style:'expanded', lineNumbers:true, compass:true }))
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('source/stylesheets'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```